# Is it true that $d(x,Y)=d(x,y_0)$ for some $y_0 \in Y$ when $Y$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Is it true that if $Y \subset X$ is a closed set and $x \notin Y$ then $\exists$ an element $y_0 \in Y$ $s.t.$ $d(x,Y)=d(x,y_0)$ where $d(x,Y)= inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y \}$ and $d: X \times X \to \mathbb R$ is a metric.

I was looking the proof of Riesz lemma and something like it came across in it. If the above is true then I will get some result in the proof.

Please someone help..

Thank you..

Comment: No. Take $X=\Bbb R-\{0\}$ under the usual metric; $y=(0,\infty)$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: You will need some form of completeness to prove things like this.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What topology are you using? $(0,\infty)$ is not a closed set with the usual one

Comment: @pwerth $X=\Bbb R-\{0\}$ under the usual metric.

Comment: @pwerth Why it is not closed? It's closed

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry I didn't see you defined $X$ like that, I assumed it was just $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It is true, though,  if $Y $ is compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $X:=\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard metric, $Y=[\pi,10]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $x=0$. Then $d(x,Y)=inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y \}=\pi$. But there is no element in $Y$ with $\pi=d(x,y_0)=|y_0|$ (not even in $X$).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard example from functional analysis. Take $X= C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the sup norm and the closed hyperplane 
$$Y=\{ f\ | \ \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f - \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f = 1\}$$

One notes that $d(0,Y)=1$, but all elements of $Y$ have norm $> 1$.